# Adding additional input fields dynamically (similar to SO careers)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Similar to the "add more experience" functionality in http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit, I want to provide a "Add another location" link which should display an additional row of a set of 4 dropdowns (country, state, city, region).  I'm actually using the CascadingDropDown jQuery Plugin for ASP.NET MVC (http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/20/cascadingdropdown-jquery-plugin-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx) for my location dropdown functionality, but I need to give the user the ability to add multiple locations.  What would be the easiest way to handle this in ASP.NET MVC and jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this: http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/9/17/jQuery--Dynamically-Adding-Form-Elements

Answer (score 0):

When I do such things I usually render PartialView's (with parameters to distinguish them) in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I keep a hidden textarea with the HTML of the elements I'm adding in it, something like:

```
<textarea style="display:none" id="template">
   <select id="{0}_state" name="{0}_state"><options....></select> 
   <select id="{0}_city" name="{0}_city"><options....></select>
</textarea>
```

Then on the event where you want to add those elements to the form, using jQuery I do something like:

```
var global_number_added = 0;
var template = jQuery.format($("#template").val());
var add_this = template(global_number_added++); //something unique
add_this.appendTo("selector_to_append_the_elements_to");
```

Hooking it up with the plugin you are using is something you'll have to look up, but you'll probably need to tie in some events to set up the cascading drop down lists.

Hope that helps.

M

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, but a pretty easy way in all asp.net is:

1. Put the form for each "additional row" in a UserControl
2. Put that section in an UpdatePanel
3. "Add another location" would cause an async postback to the UpdatePanel
4. Dynamically add an instance of the UserControl using `Page.LoadControl(..)` when they click Add Another.
5. Track the number of locations in ViewState so you know how many to render on each update.

You could also use jQuery to just copy the input form when they click "Add another," but it would be hard to make that sync up with asp.net for the postback, though not impossible, or you could just look at Request.Form to process it.

Comment: Webforms controls in mvc? It might work, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot to turn off my MVC filter when I read the question.